# Why was the concept of momentum invented in the first place, and what is its history?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Why was the concept of [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) invented in the first place, and is it useful in the different discoveries and equations that came after?

Comment: Please consider adding what you know and what you have found so far.

Comment: There was no "first place". It was a long long 2000 year slog, from [medieval impetus](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5153/55) to 17th century "quantity of motion", to distinguishing momentum and kinetic energy, with projectiles, planetary motion, falling bodies, collisions, pendula, etc., playing a part at different points. For the final stages before the concept was codified in 18th century to unify all those different contexts, see [What was the vis viva controversy?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/598/55)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a decent [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#History_of_the_concept). For more information about physics during that time period, Julian Barbour wrote an amazing book entitled *The Discovery of Dynamics*.

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestion